# adding COOP COEP HTTP Header causes third party script to stop working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

We received a message from Google that says we need to add COOP and/or COEP headers

> New requirements for [SharedArrayBuffers](https://notifications.google.com/g/p/AD-FnEwK-zjHEQNlgjyW5VFoBcKSpCup3HEmJLVgLhDk7jA32_jbXR518lBnv4VZ23V5qvEzwJ-fcbTbyhz9mm4z87ARnsqQ5G_Gpe3RDvSUNDAOYCckkPowBKw84lo3jW-1DLxqUB0ZsI_BJ_KuC0G96MxL_u7dgSH7lG1lqY8MdzVKkRNyI6CQ) on https://example.com/
> Google systems have recently detected that SharedArrayBuffers (SABs) are used on https://example.com/, but [COOP](https://notifications.google.com/g/p/AD-FnEyVcZ2sMc428lKwT0R7aqnuLThvSQGOc0F55AHrjFI2gkMmF1InZC-fbEYI4qaAcjc5gXPagMu6HKzeWShu31YP4ziryVGIK8sUlCgclKrrTiLtty2oXG1xPKpVZ0kMLL0eis_0UbHKxincS9Sr-nUAuIjoI6UadA) and/or [COEP](https://notifications.google.com/g/p/AD-FnEzl6DQp5wOVY5EPAgKFGIkrcW_V6jrB7MgTOlN_BWmUX7OJ0eiJ5g3z63EvWn9exeFUErnDCA6XaGggYyyQufPoc0vCF4Dl-_7V78rnxXhsdC2mDhcxdeoptg8bXb_CQBPWdh6rXX2fuCUwsexLNWyQdd-M0O1SWgCP) headers are not served.
> For Web Compatibility reasons Chrome is planning to require COOP/COEP for the use of SABs from Chrome 91 (2021-05-25) onwards. Please implement 'cross-origin-isolated' behavior on your site.

We added these headers accordingly.

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

and added `crossorigin` attribute to all external resources

```
<script src="https://checkoutshopper-live.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/3.4.0/adyen.js" crossorigin></script>
```

However,

**the other resources loaded by the 3rd-party external scripts** won't be loaded, and will get an `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE` error.

```
GET https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/images/analytics.png?version=3.4.0&payload_version=1&platform=web&locale=en_US&containerWidth=571&component=scheme&flavor=components net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

This is not the only 3rd-party script that is broken after adding the COOP and COEP header. Google Recaptcha v2 is broken too.

This occurs on Chrome version 89.0.4389.90

Does anyone know how to resolve this without asking each third party to change their CORS header for us?

Comment: Are you intend to use SharedArrayBuffer yourself or otherwise have you identified the resource it's using SharedArrayBuffer?

Comment: @agektmr we think it's from a certain third party library but we are not able to identify the source.

Comment: Please follow the guide here to find where it's coming from: https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/#determine-where-in-your-website-sharedarraybuffer-is-used

Comment: Thanks for insights @agektmr  We had to opt for origin trials https://developer.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/303992974847508481 since we have heavy dependency on third party scripts that do not have a plan to add support for this

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue. This got resolved after adding `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin` along with `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp` and `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin`

Instruction for same can be seen under Network requests. Please refer screenshot below.

[Info for Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdtTZ.png)

Comment: I don't think that you had the same issue that OP had. AFAIK if script it's not under his control cannot do nothing if owner of the thirdy party site does not set CORP with cross-origin. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sebelk Yes, we had to opt for origin trials https://developer.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/303992974847508481 since we have heavy dependency on third party scripts that do not have a plan to add support for this