# NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep issue on TinyMCE

Tags: node.js, express, tinymce

I'm trying to embed tinyMCE to my project and **having this issue from browser console while initializing TinyMCE**.

> **GET https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/vy3lklpfrj9a8l0jkefxe602pse728rb6ku0bqjf3i2cmqak/tinymce/5.10.3-128/themes/silver/theme.min.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200**

and this

> **GET https://sp.tinymce.com/i?aid=vy3lklpfrj9a8l0jkefxe602pse728rb6ku0bqjf3i2cmqak&tna=tinymce_cloud&p=web&dtm=1646981257782&stm=1646981257782&tz=Asia%2FSeoul&e=se&se_ca=script_load net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep**

I used script tag to add the TinyMCE...

with those errors, Nothing shows on the screen where textarea should be.

When I make an HTML file and open it with the browser, it has no problem.....

I'm trying this on  localhost and I have localhost on approved domains list of TinyMCE's dashboard.
[image]

here's my code.

first, here's my entire EJS file

##### postWrite.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        .bd-placeholder-img {
          font-size: 1.125rem;
          text-anchor: middle;
          -webkit-user-select: none;
          -moz-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
        }
  
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
          .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
            font-size: 3.5rem;
          }
        }

        .nav-pills > .nav-item > .active {
          color : white;
          background-color : black;
        }
      
      </style>
      <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/(MY-API-KEY)/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
      <script>
          tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea'
          });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container">
        <div class="d-flex flex-fill py-3 mb-4 border-bottom p-3">
          <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-decoration-none text-body">
            <span class="fs-4 ms-3">HKJang's Blog</span>
          </a>
    
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/" class="nav-link text-body" >About Me</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="project" class="nav-link active">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="index_admin" class="nav-link text-body" aria-current="page">Modify Index</a></li>
          </ul>

          <form class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-2">
            <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-dark ms-3" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
          </form>
          <form>
            <button class="btn btn-dark my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </header>
  <main class="container">
    <form method="post">
        <textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
    </form>
  </main>
  <footer class="container">

  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the part that I'm having trouble on is

```
...
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/(MY-API-KEY)/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
      <script>
          tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea'
          });
      </script>
...
...
<main class="container">
    <form method="post">
        <textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
    </form>
  </main>
...
```

this EJS file is rendered by controller.

##### projectController.js

```
const boardView = async(req, res) => {
    res.render("boardView", {});
};

const postView = async(req, res) => {
    res.render("postView", {});
};

const postWriteView = (req, res) => {
    res.render("postWrite", {});
}

module.exports = {
    boardView,
    postView,
    postWriteView
};
```

and finally, this is index.js file for my server

##### index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const compression = require('compression');
const csp = require('helmet-csp');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // bodyparser : post 방식 body parsing용 -> express 기본 탑재
app.use(express.json());

var corsOption = {
  origin: 'localhost',
  credentials:'true'
}

app.use(cors(corsOption));

app.use(helmet());
app.use(
    csp({
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self' 'sha256-uts7zrnGYAKZNfvBc7PYcShvKP4t10vo5qemd5Yp0lc=' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/vy3lklpfrj9a8l0jkefxe602pse728rb6ku0bqjf3i2cmqak/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js"],
        imgSrc: ["'self' https://blogprojectbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ https://blogprojectbucket.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com"]
      },
    })
  );

app.use(compression());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/board'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
app.use('/project', require('./routes/project'))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, console.log("Server start  at port : "+PORT));
```

Btw, I've tried to open all CORS configuration by trying **app.use(cors())**

Please help!

Comment: Try adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the script element that’s fetching tinymce.min.js; like this: `<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/(MY-API-KEY)/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>`. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70969504/441757

Comment: It removed "write:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined at write:36:11" this error, but while initialzing TinyMCE, another CORS issue happens..

Comment: I've changed my question to current issue..

Answer (score 0):

So this is proper way to use TinyMCE if you're using an Express app:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/expressjs/

You have to npm install TinyMCE and use it.