# CSP error while using node.js server while serving files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

First I thought it was a frontend problem but no it was not.

I'm using helmet in my node application which is causing CSP errors while loading 3rd party scripts.

**My HTML Code**

```
script(src='https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js')
script(src='https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js')
script(src='https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js')
script(src='https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js')
```

I have included the above scripts in my head tag in my pug file.

**Error Caused by helmet**

```
Refused to load the script 'https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js' because it 
violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 
'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

127.0.0.1/:1 Refused to load the script 
'https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js' because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was 
not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

127.0.0.1/:1 Refused to load the script 
'https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js' because it violates the 
following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src- 
elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

127.0.0.1/:1 Refused to load the script 
'https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js' because it violates the 
following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src- 
elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

***Solutions I have tried in my `app.js` file***

```
app.use(helmet());

app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
      imgSrc: ["'self'", "https: data:"],
      scriptSrc: [
        "'self'",
        "https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js",
        "https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js",
        "https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js",
      ],
    },
  })
);

app.use(
  helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({
    policy: "cross-origin",
  })
);

Allow-access-control-allow-origin *
app.use(cors());
```

- Removing the helmet middleware solves the problem, but it's necessary to use for security reason.

**Error I'm getting after implementing the above solution.**

```
127.0.0.1/:1 GET https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js 
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200

127.0.0.1/:1 GET https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200

127.0.0.1/:1 GET https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200
```

I'm new to backend-dev. Please help me to solve the above issue and I would appreciate a safe solution rather than a workaround solution. I've gone through the MDN docs about **CORS,CSP** but it was overwhelming.

**Headers**

```
cross-origin-resource-policy To use this resource from a different 
origin, the server needs to specify a cross-origin resource policy 
in the response headers: 

Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same- siteChoose this option if the 
resource and the document are served 
from the same site.
```

This is the header error generated.

Comment: What headers is the helmet contentSecurityPolicy  generating on the html response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent ERR\_BLOCKED\_BY\_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832906/how-to-prevent-err-blocked-by-response-notsameoriginafterdefaultedtosameoriginby)

Comment: cross-origin-resource-policy

To use this resource from a different origin, the server needs to specify a cross-origin resource policy in the response headers:

Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-siteChoose this option if the resource and the document are served from the same site.

This is the header error generated.